# Make multiple divs exchange background on hover

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs, one is bigger, other 3 are equally small. When I hover on one of the small ones, I want the big one to get the background-image that the small one has. Is this possible in CSS alone?

I've got the following so far:

```css
.mar {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-image: url("http://www.scrapsyard.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Nature.jpeg");
}

#n1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uZA6pIrwm-I/maxresdefault.jpg");
}

#n2 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-image: url("http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/some_are_different-wide.jpg");
}

#n3 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TGLYcYCm2FM/maxresdefault.jpg");
}

.mi:hover ~ .mar {
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mar">
</div>
<div class="mi" id="n1">
</div>
<div class="mi" id="n2">
</div>
<div class="mi" id="n3">
</div>
```

So when hovering over a div with class `mi`, I want the background-image of div with `mar` to change into the one of the `mi`'s. Is it possible?

Comment: No...with the current structure you need javascript.

Comment: Is there a way to restructure it to make it work only with css though?

Comment: Yes...put the big div after the little ones.

Comment: How would that help? I still don't know to to take the images from the little divs

Comment: @Melye77 If you put big div after the little ones and use `position` to make it appear first, then you can use adjacent and general sibling selectors in CSS to accomplish with you want

Comment: Well for that you WILL need JS (or a whole bunch of CSS)...I was referring to the CSS selector you were using..`~` is for subsequent siblings.

Comment: @Melye77, TylerH is referring to the fact that CSS can't target parent selectors (elements higher-up in the markup), it can only target sibling selectors (elements positioned lower in the markup)

Comment: Yea, the hover works now... but I want the image to change using only css

Comment: If you want to use some JQuery https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/187/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to was add this css

```
#n1:hover ~ .mar {
   background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uZA6pIrwm-I/maxresdefault.jpg");  
}

#n2:hover ~ .mar {
   background-image: url("http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/some_are_different-wide.jpg");
}

#n3:hover ~ .mar {
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TGLYcYCm2FM/maxresdefault.jpg");
}
```

And place the .mar div at the end like so:

```
<div class="mi" id="n1">
</div>
<div class="mi" id="n2">
</div>
<div class="mi" id="n3">
</div>
<div class="mar">
</div>
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/7jxx59fy/) a fiddle, hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Ah ok so I can't do it work on any number of divs without writting the same   #n1:hover ~ .mar {
   background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uZA6pIrwm-I/maxresdefault.jpg");  
} code over and over?

Comment: No i don't think so, not with css, but I'm sure in jQuery you can get the image of the div you are hovering, and make it the background image for the big div, but not with css. On second thought, have you thought about using a preprocessor ?

Comment: @SamirChahine Even with a pre-processor it will still compile to the same CSS. Oh, it will make it easier to write...but the end result is the same. This kind of thing is much better left to JS.JQ.

Comment: Yes of course, but if OP wants to stay with CSS, then Sass or a similar preprocessor is much better, they can create an array of all the image sources and loop through them, but yes, jQuery is the right language for this problem.