# Hover over one list element, affect a div Only CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists

Ok so i have a list of elements and once I hover over one of them, I want the content of a "text box div" to change accordingly. I've looked online over and over and none of the results helped

```
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="tohover" id="m1"><a href=#>Home</a></div>
    <div class="tohover" id="m2"><a href=#>Mail</a></div>
    <div class="tohover" id="m3"><a href=#>Sports</a></div>
    <div class="tohover" id="m4"><a href=#>Movies</a></div>
    <div class="centermenu">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel molestie nulla, eu tincidunt purus. Phasellus eget ligula orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque mollis varius ex et</p>
    </div></div>
```

And the css part would be something like:

```
.centermenu {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #606060;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
}

p {
  padding: 5px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.tohover > a {
  color: black;
}

#m1:hover ~ .centermenu {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But it is not working. It's not doing anything. Any ideas why? This ~ worked with images but now it doesn't anymore.

I'm thinking about using the ::before ::after but they don't replace the text... which I want

Comment: Can't do it without JavaScript. There's no parent selector in CSS yet so you have no way to get access to the div by hovering the links or list items.

Comment: I posted this a few weeks ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972663/make-multiple-divs-exchange-background-on-hover I want to do the same but with a list and I will change the text from the centermenu. How do I do it? It's not working but it worked before

Comment: The HTML structure in your other question is entirely different that what you have above, and that makes the difference.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate..but of which one...there are so many to choose from? :)

Comment: I also kinda of specified it is a duplicate but I didn't find my answer in any of the others and I was looking for the specific reason why using the ~ is not working

Comment: the specific reason is tat CSS selector can only go down the dom from parent to child or from one element to next (both together works) For what you wanna do, CSS can not. javascript is here to do these kind of jobs. else some trolling codes could do something alike but not at all in fact and not usable anyway: a troll example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZRZqJ where you hover the div in fact (arrow)

Comment: That is way too complicated. Can I change my code in any way to get the wanted result? http://codepen.io/LisaFort/pen/wGeJwK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this solution. your best choice though is jQuery/javascript.
https://jsfiddle.net/vp02x56o/7/

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="tohover" id="m1"><a href=#>Home</a></div>
    <div class="tohover" id="m2"><a href=#>Mail</a></div>
    <div class="tohover" id="m3"><a href=#>Sports</a></div>
    <div class="tohover" id="m4"><a href=#>Movies</a></div>
    <div class="centermenu" id="c1">
        <p>1111111111</p>
    </div>
    <div class="centermenu" id="c2">
        <p>222222222222222</p>
    </div>
    <div class="centermenu" id="c3">
        <p>3333333333</p>
    </div>
    <div class="centermenu" id="c4">
        <p>4444444444444444</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .centermenu {
      display:none;
      background-color: #F9F9F9;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      width: 1000px;
      margin-top: 70px;
      margin-left: 40px;
      border: 1px solid #606060;
      height: auto;
      color: black;
      word-wrap: break-word; 
    }

    p {
      padding: 5px;
      text-indent: 10px;
    }

    .tohover > a {
      color: black;
    }

    #c1.centermenu {
      display: block;
    }


    #m1:hover ~ #c1 {
      display: block;
    }


    #m2:hover ~ #c2 {
      display: block;
    }
    #m2:hover ~ #c1 {
      display: none;
    }


    #m3:hover ~ #c3 {
      display: block;
    }
    #m3:hover ~ #c1 {
      display: none;
    }


    #m4:hover ~ #c4 {
      display: block;
    }
    #m4:hover ~ #c1 {
      display: none;
    }
```

Comment: This could work, I just need a default text too that would stay there until I hover over menu

Answer (score 1):

Only with CSS you can't reach that. Only if move ".centrermenu" div inside `<ul>`. But it is really easy to do with javascript or Jquery for example

Comment: I did it before with photos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972663/make-multiple-divs-exchange-background-on-hover For some reason, it's not working now and I don't understand why. I want to use only css

Comment: You did it before, because all the elements where on the same level. In this example elements are on different levels. You can achieve it when you'll move <div class="centermenu"> inside <ul>

Comment: I changed things a little. How about now? They are all children of the same parent

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned jQuery is your best bet but you could do something like this although I wouldn't recommend it,

https://jsfiddle.net/eor0gmsg/

```
.centermenu {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #606060;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
}

p {
  padding: 5px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.tohover > a {
  color: black;
}

#m1:hover ~ .centermenu:before  {
  background-color: red;
   content: "Lorem ipsum";

}

#m1:hover ~ .centermenu{
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: Hah yea that's merely changing the color. Can't I remove the content in any way and then apply the before?

Comment: Something like this http://codepen.io/Jintos/pen/rolim  or http://ahrengot.com/tutorials/switching-text-with-css/ My codepen is this http://codepen.io/LisaFort/pen/wGeJwK